# Kendo mvc refreshing cell value

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm trying to refresh grid cell using javascript. I'm refering to two cells which I want to refresh, but command refresh() or read() doesn't working:

[Refresh()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV8VH.png)

[Read()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp9K2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way you can update cell value in grid .

1.In data bound event

```
function Grid_DataBound(e) {
    var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
          var row = $(rows[j]);
          row[0].cells[i].innerHTML = 'Your UpdatedText ';
    }
}
```

2.In inline control event (client template) i.e. your column needs to be define as a ClientTemplate having any control and call a function on any of the event.

```
function ControlChange(args) {
     var currentRow = $(args.currentTarget).closest("tr")[0];
     //If needed you can access datasource
     var dataItem = $("#Report_Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(currentRow);

     currentRow.cells[4].innerHTML  = 'Your UpdatedText ';

}
```